# How to replace expiring Service Communication Certificates in ADFS 2.0

Tags: ssl-certificate, adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm, federated

We have an ADFS 2.0 deployment which is used to provide claims-based authentication to our Dynamics CRM 2011 system.  There are 2 ADFS servers in place.  One is in the corporate user Active Directory domain while the other is in the secured production Active Directory domain (to which the deployed CRM servers belong).

The certificates which are being replaced are used for Service Communications in ADFS.  Are there any special steps that should be completed to replace the expiring certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Good write up here:

[AD FS 2.0: How to Replace the SSL, Service Communications, Token-Signing, and Token-Decrypting Certificates](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2554.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-replace-the-ssl-service-communications-token-signing-and-token-decrypting-certificates.aspx).